# Display result from server in IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have implemented HTTP adapter in IBM Worklight. I want to display the result  returned from server. I want to display HTML file. My code is

```
function getFeeds() {
    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'text',
        path : "marketing/partners.html"
    };
    WL.Logger.debug("sdfsds");
    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);


}
```

I want to receive(display) `WL.Server.invokeHttp(input)`. After receiving it I want to parse the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Server-side Development Getting Started Modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development). Inside the [HTTP adapter – Communicating with HTTP back-end systems Module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf) on Slide 15 - 'XSL Transformation Filtering' will show you how to filter data you get back from the backend. Further parsing and showing data has to be done on the client using onSuccess callback for [WL.Client.invokeProcedure](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_invokeprocedure.html). There's a module for that [too](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/04_06_Invoking_adapter_procedures_from_client_applications.pdf).

Here's an example of getting data and showing to a user:

```
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'adapter-name',
    procedure : 'procedure-name',
    parameters : []
};

var options = {};

options.onSuccess = function (response) {
       //response is a JavaScript object
       $("#id").html(response.invocationResponse.text);
}

options.onFailure = function (response) {
       alert('Failed!'); //You probably want something more meaningful here.
}

WL.Client invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
```

There are JavaScript libraries you can add to make searching for values inside the JSON response easier, such as: [jspath](https://github.com/dfilatov/jspath) and [jquery-jspath](https://github.com/thatcher/jquery-jspath). There's also [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) if you're working with XML.

Answer (score 2):

If you retrieve it as plain text, once you got it back to your application, do something like

```
$("#container-id").html(response.invocationResponse.text);
```

This will inject the HTML you've retrieved to an element with id `container-id`.